# Train ML Classification Mode

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to train a model to determine the position of a person and his stance by coordinates. I need Multi-output classification model.
So I have csv data:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df = pd.read_csv('deadlift.csv')
df.head()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXufg.png)
Then I split the data:

```
X = df.drop(['class', 'stand'], axis=1)
y = df[['class', 'stand']]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=1234)
X_train.shape
```

(33, 132)

```
y_train.shape
```

(33, 2)
Afterwards I train model:

```
model1 = Pipeline(steps=[('cv', CountVectorizer(lowercase=False)), ('lr_multi', MultiOutputClassifier(LogisticRegression()))])
model1.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And got the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[363], line 1
----> 1 model1.fit(X_train, y_train)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:1152, in _fit_context.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1145     estimator._validate_params()
   1147 with config_context(
   1148     skip_parameter_validation=(
   1149         prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1150     )
   1151 ):
-> 1152     return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:427, in Pipeline.fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    425     if self._final_estimator != "passthrough":
    426         fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 427         self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    429 return self

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\multioutput.py:538, in MultiOutputClassifier.fit(self, X, Y, sample_weight, **fit_params)
    512 def fit(self, X, Y, sample_weight=None, **fit_params):
    513     """Fit the model to data matrix X and targets Y.
    514 
    515     Parameters
   (...)
    536         Returns a fitted instance.
    537     """
--> 538     super().fit(X, Y, sample_weight=sample_weight, **fit_params)
    539     self.classes_ = [estimator.classes_ for estimator in self.estimators_]
    540     return self

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:1152, in _fit_context.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1145     estimator._validate_params()
   1147 with config_context(
   1148     skip_parameter_validation=(
   1149         prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1150     )
   1151 ):
-> 1152     return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\multioutput.py:273, in _MultiOutputEstimator.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, **fit_params)
    270     if sample_weight is not None:
    271         routed_params.estimator.fit["sample_weight"] = sample_weight
--> 273 self.estimators_ = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
    274     delayed(_fit_estimator)(
    275         self.estimator, X, y[:, i], **routed_params.estimator.fit
    276     )
    277     for i in range(y.shape[1])
    278 )
    280 if hasattr(self.estimators_[0], "n_features_in_"):
    281     self.n_features_in_ = self.estimators_[0].n_features_in_

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\parallel.py:65, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
     60 config = get_config()
     61 iterable_with_config = (
     62     (_with_config(delayed_func, config), args, kwargs)
     63     for delayed_func, args, kwargs in iterable
     64 )
---> 65 return super().__call__(iterable_with_config)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:1863, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
   1861     output = self._get_sequential_output(iterable)
   1862     next(output)
-> 1863     return output if self.return_generator else list(output)
   1865 # Let's create an ID that uniquely identifies the current call. If the
   1866 # call is interrupted early and that the same instance is immediately
   1867 # re-used, this id will be used to prevent workers that were
   1868 # concurrently finalizing a task from the previous call to run the
   1869 # callback.
   1870 with self._lock:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:1792, in Parallel._get_sequential_output(self, iterable)
   1790 self.n_dispatched_batches += 1
   1791 self.n_dispatched_tasks += 1
-> 1792 res = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1793 self.n_completed_tasks += 1
   1794 self.print_progress()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\parallel.py:127, in _FuncWrapper.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    125     config = {}
    126 with config_context(**config):
--> 127     return self.function(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\multioutput.py:60, in _fit_estimator(estimator, X, y, sample_weight, **fit_params)
     58     estimator.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight, **fit_params)
     59 else:
---> 60     estimator.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
     61 return estimator

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:1152, in _fit_context.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1145     estimator._validate_params()
   1147 with config_context(
   1148     skip_parameter_validation=(
   1149         prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1150     )
   1151 ):
-> 1152     return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py:1208, in LogisticRegression.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1205 else:
   1206     _dtype = [np.float64, np.float32]
-> 1208 X, y = self._validate_data(
   1209     X,
   1210     y,
   1211     accept_sparse="csr",
   1212     dtype=_dtype,
   1213     order="C",
   1214     accept_large_sparse=solver not in ["liblinear", "sag", "saga"],
   1215 )
   1216 check_classification_targets(y)
   1217 self.classes_ = np.unique(y)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:622, in BaseEstimator._validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, cast_to_ndarray, **check_params)
    620         y = check_array(y, input_name="y", **check_y_params)
    621     else:
--> 622         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    623     out = X, y
    625 if not no_val_X and check_params.get("ensure_2d", True):

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:1164, in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
   1146 X = check_array(
   1147     X,
   1148     accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
   (...)
   1159     input_name="X",
   1160 )
   1162 y = _check_y(y, multi_output=multi_output, y_numeric=y_numeric, estimator=estimator)
-> 1164 check_consistent_length(X, y)
   1166 return X, y

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:407, in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    405 uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    406 if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 407     raise ValueError(
    408         "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: %r"
    409         % [int(l) for l in lengths]
    410     )

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [132, 33]
```

If I use one class all worked, but i want to use two classes

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, i.e. your data not as picture but rather a minimal reproducible example dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are referencing a different variable in your `train_test_split`, not `y` but `y3`. The latter seems to have a different shape than your `X`.